# How to render a SlimDX scene directly to a GDI bitmap

Tags: gdi, slimdx

Is there a way to set the render target to a GDI bitmap in SlimDX so that as soon as the scene is rendered I can immediately BitBlt the render out of there for processing in another thread and continue rendering?

Is it necessary to render to a texture and then copy the contents out to the bitmap?  I would like to be able to do this without any unnecessary copying.  I'm going to need every speedup I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, you do need to render to a RenderTarget then copy that resource into a Texture2D then you can map the data and get the pixels into your bitmap.

The memory for RenderTargets is marked for a special kind of use by the graphics card and cannot be read from directly

The memory for Textures can be marked so that it can be read but only through the API as it is still held on the graphics card (some exceptions but DirectX has to go with the lowest common denominator)

If you need the extra speed reuse the same bitmap or have an array of prepared bitmaps ready to fill and keep them on rotation.

And as ever, measure how much time these things are consuming with a profiler so that you can quantify bottlenecks.